# Loading relationships using spring-data-neo4j

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I am attaching below two simple nodes which are connected by a relationship. I am omitting constructors and getters and setters for brevity.

```
@NodeEntity
public class Person {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  @Relationship(type = "ACTED_IN")
  private List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

}


@NodeEntity
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("movie")
    @Relationship(type = "ACTED_IN", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private List<Role> roles;

}

@RelationshipEntity(type = "ACTED_IN")
public class Role {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @StartNode
  private Person person;

  @EndNode
  private Movie movie;
}
```

My question is as follows. If if load a person by using a repository interface, I see that the movies list in person is always empty. This happens even if the person has a relationship("ACTED_IN") with a movie.

If I load a Movie meanwhile, I see that the roles list is populated correctly. **Is this the expected behaviour?**  It somehow feels odd to me? Can somebody give a better explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the type of your relationship in `Person` from `List<Movie>` to `List<Role>`.
If you load the `Person` with the current construct, Neo4j-OGM (the mapping library behind Spring Data Neo4j) does not know which is the correct relationship because you defined the `ACTED_IN` type for `Person` to `Movie`s not only for a "just typed" relationship by the `@Relationship` annotation, but also as a `@RelationshipEntity`.

Changing the `@Relationship` to also point to the `@RelationshipEntity` will solve the problem.

Comment: That makes sense, I also tried it out and it works. I was hoping spring data would be able to figure it out based on the StartNode and the EndNode annotations.
It is a bit counter intuitive as I can add a movie to the person. And when i save the person the relationship gets automatically created!! But it cant figure the movie based on the person.

Comment: The mapping lib behind Spring Data Neo4j Neo4j-OGM does the save as you mapped it. When it comes to loading it has to find unambiguous information for the correct mapping. Since there are two "rivals", the direct relationship in the `Person` and the relationship entity `Role`, it cannot be sure what to create (just add it to the `movies` list or create a `Role` object).